# Pandas divide every nth row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to use every 5th row as a reference row (`ref_row`), divide this `ref_row` starting from this `ref_row` and do the same for the next 4 rows.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    
len = df.shape[0]

for idx in range(0,len,5):

    ref_row = df.iloc[idx:idx+1,:]

    for idx_next in range(idx,idx+5):

        df.iloc[idx_next:idx_next+1,:] = df.iloc[idx_next:idx_next+1,:].div(ref_row)
```

However, I got all `NaN` except the `ref_row`.

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN
... ... ... ... ...
95  1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
96  NaN NaN NaN NaN
97  NaN NaN NaN NaN
98  NaN NaN NaN NaN
99  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that with `df.iloc[idx_next:idx_next+1,:]` and `df.iloc[idx:idx+1,:]`, you're indexing df rows as DF objects. So when you divide, the indices don't match and you get NaN. Replace

```
df.iloc[idx_next:idx_next+1,:]
```

with

```
df.iloc[idx_next]
```

and

```
df.iloc[idx:idx+1,:]
```

with

```
df.iloc[idx]
```

everywhere, it will work as expected (because they're now Series objects, so the indices match).

You can also repeat the array of every fifth row of the DataFrame using `np.repeat` on `axis=0`, then element-wise divide it with the resulting array:

```
out = df.div(np.repeat(df[::5].to_numpy(), 5, axis=0))
```

Output:

```
           A         B         C         D
0   1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
1   0.726190  0.359375  0.967742  1.644068
2   0.130952  0.046875  0.161290  0.406780
3   0.488095  0.312500  0.919355  0.305085
4   0.857143  0.203125  0.967742  0.525424
..       ...       ...       ...       ...
95  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
96  0.061224  1.400000  0.518519  0.882353
97  1.510204  1.300000  1.740741  5.588235
98  0.224490  2.100000  1.407407  0.294118
99  1.061224  1.400000  1.388889  3.411765

[100 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: @JohnnyTam the problem with your code is that with `df.iloc[idx_next:idx_next+1,:].div(ref_row)` and `df.iloc[idx:idx+1,:]`, you're selecting indexing df rows as DF objects. so when you divide, the indices don't match and you get NaN. Replace `df.iloc[idx_next:idx_next+1,:]` with `df.iloc[idx_next, :]` and `df.iloc[idx:idx+1,:]` with `df.iloc[idx, :]` everywhere, it will work as expected (because they're now Series objects, so the indices match).

Comment: Hi enke, something strange happened. `np.repeat(df[::5].to_numpy(), 5, axis=0)` changed the shape (added two extra columns) when I apply this code to a larger dataframe, giving an error `Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (8088, 0): given (8090, 0)`. Do you know what could be the possibility?

Comment: I discovered why: the num of rows of df should be multiples of n.

Comment: @JohnnyTam yes, `np.repeat` creates an `len(df)%5*5 x df.shape[1]` array, so if `len(df)%5*5 != len(df)`, the lengths won't match. But you can always just slice the array by the length of `df`: `df.div(np.repeat(df[::5].to_numpy(), 5, axis=0)[:len(df)])`